# Nunjucks error reporting on imported file

Tags: nunjucks

With Nunjucks I use the `throwOnUndefined` option to see where I use an undefined or null value in my output.

In my code structure I have a main file, and import files containing macro's for the actual rendering of output.

I want to report errors on, but the errors are always reported on the main file. Both in my own code, and when I use for example nunjucks-cli.

An example with nunjucks-cli:

file `options.json`:

```json
{
    "throwOnUndefined": true,
}
```

file `test.njk`:

```
{% import "macro.njk" as doit %}
{{ doit.giveError("x") }}
```

file `macro.njk`, containing an error because writing value of `y`:

```
{% macro giveError(x) %}
   {{ y }} 
{% endmacro %}
```

Nunjucks commando:

```
nunjucks test.njk --path . --options options.json
```

Error output:

```
Template render error: (C:\Q\nunjucks-errorreporting\test.njk) [Line 1, Column 17]
  Template render error: (C:\Q\nunjucks-errorreporting\test.njk) [Line 2, Column 4]
  attempted to output null or undefined value
```

Both errors are reported on `test.njk`. The first error on `Line 1, Column 17`, but on both files there is no relevance on column 17. The second error is `Line 2, Column 4`, which matches with writing out `{{ y }}` in the `macro.njk` file, but is reported on `test.njk`.

I get the same behaviour in my custom code.

Is there a way to get correct error reporting on the correct files, because I have file importing files, importing other files...

**Update:**

Based on input Lesha Ogonkov I added `"dev": true` to the options.json.
This results in the following output:

```
Error: attempted to output null or undefined value
    at new TemplateError (C:\Q\nunjucks-errorreporting\node_modules\nunjucks\src\lib.js:89:17)
    at Object.ensureDefined (C:\Q\nunjucks-errorreporting\node_modules\nunjucks\src\runtime.js:242:11)
    at Object.eval (eval at _compile (C:\Q\nunjucks-errorreporting\node_modules\nunjucks\src\environment.js:631:18), <anonymous>:18:38)
    at Object.giveError (C:\Q\nunjucks-errorreporting\node_modules\nunjucks\src\runtime.js:131:17)
    at Context.<anonymous> (C:\Q\nunjucks-errorreporting\node_modules\nunjucks\src\runtime.js:259:23)
    at Object.callWrap (C:\Q\nunjucks-errorreporting\node_modules\nunjucks\src\runtime.js:273:14)
    at eval (eval at _compile (C:\Q\nunjucks-errorreporting\node_modules\nunjucks\src\environment.js:631:18), <anonymous>:13:88)
    at C:\Q\nunjucks-errorreporting\node_modules\nunjucks\src\environment.js:613:9
    at Template.root [as rootRenderFunc] (eval at _compile (C:\Q\nunjucks-errorreporting\node_modules\nunjucks\src\environment.js:631:18), <anonymous>:29:1)
    at Template.getExported (C:\Q\nunjucks-errorreporting\node_modules\nunjucks\src\environment.js:609:10) {
  lineno: 2,
  colno: 4,
  firstUpdate: false,
  Update: [Function: Update]
}
```

I still not see a relation to the file where the error is occurring.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `dev` flag next to `throwOnUndefined`. It is undocumented nunjucks feature, that prevent stacktrace collapse.

Comment: But the extra stacktrace information does not give a clue of the file the error occurred in.

Comment: What is your stacktrace shows with `dev: true`?

Comment: Lesha, I tried to paste the output here but was too large so added it to the question. Still see no relation to the file where the error is occurring.

Comment: Sorry, looks like it is not working like i expect